# Opencv Camera megapixels Android

Tags: opencv, camera, resolution

i am new with Opencv.I use JavaCameraView, 
which uses 1280x 720 camera resolution.
How can I increase the resolution to 5 megapixels?
Please help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pick a resolution that is allowed by your camera.  Call the following code in your onCameraViewStarted function and set listNum so that it corresponds to the resolution you desire:

```
Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
List<Size> resList = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes();
int listNum = 1;// 0 is the maximum resolution
int width = resList.get(listNum).width;
int height = resList.get(listNum).height;
params.setPictureSize(width, height);
mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

mCamera is your org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView object.

Brian

Answer (score 1):

It seems that OpenCV Camera (JavaCameraView) has been set to default maximum resolution of 1280*720.

We can decrease the resolution using:

`cameraView.setMaxFrameSize(320, 280);`
Or

```
cameraView.setMaxFrameSize(480, 320);
```

Or

```
cameraView.setMaxFrameSize(640, 480);
```

Or

```
cameraView.setMaxFrameSize(800, 600);
```

Or

```
cameraView.setMaxFrameSize(1280, 720);
```

Now, the question is how to increase the resolution after that, if my mobile supports more resolution. For that we have to make our own customized JavaCameraView (Let's say MyCameraView).

Just copy and paste JavaCameraView to MyCameraView and do corrections according to your need.

I do the following corrections in my case:

```
package com.example.opencvcamera;

import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;

import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

/**
 * Created by Kumar.Vaibhav on 19-04-2017.
 */

public class MyCameraView extends CameraBridgeViewBase implements Camera.PreviewCallback {
    private static final int MAGIC_TEXTURE_ID = 10;
    private static final String TAG = "MyCameraView";

    private byte mBuffer[];
    private Mat[] mFrameChain;
    private int mChainIdx = 0;
    private Thread mThread;
    private boolean mStopThread;

    protected Camera mCamera;
    protected MyCameraView.JavaCameraFrame[] mCameraFrame;
    private SurfaceTexture mSurfaceTexture;

    public static class JavaCameraSizeAccessor implements ListItemAccessor {

        @Override
        public int getWidth(Object obj) {
            Camera.Size size = (Camera.Size) obj;
            return size.width;
        }

        @Override
        public int getHeight(Object obj) {
            Camera.Size size = (Camera.Size) obj;
            return size.height;
        }
    }

    public MyCameraView(Context context, int cameraId) {
        super(context, cameraId);
    }

    public MyCameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    protected boolean initializeCamera(int width, int height) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Initialize java camera");
        boolean result = true;
        synchronized (this) {
            mCamera = null;

            if (mCameraIndex == CAMERA_ID_ANY) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Trying to open camera with old open()");
                try {
                    mCamera = Camera.open();
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e(TAG, "Camera is not available (in use or does not exist): " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }

                if(mCamera == null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
                    boolean connected = false;
                    for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); ++camIdx) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to open camera with new open(" + Integer.valueOf(camIdx) + ")");
                        try {
                            mCamera = Camera.open(camIdx);
                            connected = true;
                        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Camera #" + camIdx + "failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                        if (connected) break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
                    int localCameraIndex = mCameraIndex;
                    if (mCameraIndex == CAMERA_ID_BACK) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Trying to open back camera");
                        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
                        for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); ++camIdx) {
                            Camera.getCameraInfo( camIdx, cameraInfo );
                            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                                localCameraIndex = camIdx;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (mCameraIndex == CAMERA_ID_FRONT) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Trying to open front camera");
                        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
                        for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); ++camIdx) {
                            Camera.getCameraInfo( camIdx, cameraInfo );
                            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                                localCameraIndex = camIdx;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (localCameraIndex == CAMERA_ID_BACK) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Back camera not found!");
                    } else if (localCameraIndex == CAMERA_ID_FRONT) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Front camera not found!");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to open camera with new open(" + Integer.valueOf(localCameraIndex) + ")");
                        try {
                            mCamera = Camera.open(localCameraIndex);
                        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Camera #" + localCameraIndex + "failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (mCamera == null)
                return false;

            /* Now set camera parameters */
            try {
                Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                Log.d(TAG, "getSupportedPreviewSizes()");
                List<android.hardware.Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

                if (sizes != null) {
                    /* Select the size that fits surface considering maximum size allowed */
                    //Size frameSize = calculateCameraFrameSize(sizes, new MyCameraView.JavaCameraSizeAccessor(), width, height);

                    Camera.Size mSizePicture =sizes.get(0);
                    if(mSizePicture.width<3264 && mSizePicture.height<2448)
                    {
                        int cameraSize= sizes.size();
                        mSizePicture =sizes.get(cameraSize-1);
                    }
                    /*params.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Set preview size to " + Integer.valueOf((int)frameSize.width) + "x" + Integer.valueOf((int)frameSize.height));
                    params.setPreviewSize((int)frameSize.width, (int)frameSize.height);

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH && !android.os.Build.MODEL.equals("GT-I9100"))
                        params.setRecordingHint(true);*/

                    List<String> FocusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
                    if (FocusModes != null && FocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO))
                    {
                        params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
                    }

                    mCamera.setParameters(params);
                    params = mCamera.getParameters();

                    mFrameWidth = params.getPreviewSize().width;
                    mFrameHeight = params.getPreviewSize().height;

                    if ((getLayoutParams().width == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) && (getLayoutParams().height == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT))
                        mScale = Math.min(((float)height)/mFrameHeight, ((float)width)/mFrameWidth);
                    else
                        mScale = 0;

                    if (mFpsMeter != null) {
                        mFpsMeter.setResolution(mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight);
                    }

                    int size = mFrameWidth * mFrameHeight;
                    size  = size * ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(params.getPreviewFormat()) / 8;
                    mBuffer = new byte[size];

                    mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer);
                    mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);

                    mFrameChain = new Mat[2];
                    mFrameChain[0] = new Mat(mFrameHeight + (mFrameHeight/2), mFrameWidth, CvType.CV_8UC1);
                    mFrameChain[1] = new Mat(mFrameHeight + (mFrameHeight/2), mFrameWidth, CvType.CV_8UC1);

                    AllocateCache();

                    mCameraFrame = new MyCameraView.JavaCameraFrame[2];
                    mCameraFrame[0] = new MyCameraView.JavaCameraFrame(mFrameChain[0], mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight);
                    mCameraFrame[1] = new MyCameraView.JavaCameraFrame(mFrameChain[1], mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight);

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                        mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(MAGIC_TEXTURE_ID);
                        mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mSurfaceTexture);
                    } else
                        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);

                    /* Finally we are ready to start the preview */
                    Log.d(TAG, "startPreview");
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                }
                else
                    result = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                result = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected void releaseCamera() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

                mCamera.release();
            }
            mCamera = null;
            if (mFrameChain != null) {
                mFrameChain[0].release();
                mFrameChain[1].release();
            }
            if (mCameraFrame != null) {
                mCameraFrame[0].release();
                mCameraFrame[1].release();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean mCameraFrameReady = false;

    @Override
    protected boolean connectCamera(int width, int height) {

        /* 1. We need to instantiate camera
         * 2. We need to start thread which will be getting frames
         */
        /* First step - initialize camera connection */
        Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to camera");
        if (!initializeCamera(width, height))
            return false;

        mCameraFrameReady = false;

        /* now we can start update thread */
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting processing thread");
        mStopThread = false;
        mThread = new Thread(new CameraWorker());
        mThread.start();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void disconnectCamera() {
        /* 1. We need to stop thread which updating the frames
         * 2. Stop camera and release it
         */
        Log.d(TAG, "Disconnecting from camera");
        try {
            mStopThread = true;
            Log.d(TAG, "Notify thread");
            synchronized (this) {
                this.notify();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Wating for thread");
            if (mThread != null)
                mThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            mThread =  null;
        }

        /* Now release camera */
        releaseCamera();

        mCameraFrameReady = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] frame, Camera arg1) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Preview Frame received. Frame size: " + frame.length);
        synchronized (this) {
            mFrameChain[mChainIdx].put(0, 0, frame);
            mCameraFrameReady = true;
            this.notify();
        }
        if (mCamera != null)
            mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer);
    }

    private class JavaCameraFrame implements CvCameraViewFrame {
        @Override
        public Mat gray() {
            return mYuvFrameData.submat(0, mHeight, 0, mWidth);
        }

        @Override
        public Mat rgba() {
            Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuvFrameData, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21, 4);
            return mRgba;
        }

        public JavaCameraFrame(Mat Yuv420sp, int width, int height) {
            super();
            mWidth = width;
            mHeight = height;
            mYuvFrameData = Yuv420sp;
            mRgba = new Mat();
        }

        public void release() {
            mRgba.release();
        }

        private Mat mYuvFrameData;
        private Mat mRgba;
        private int mWidth;
        private int mHeight;
    };

    private class CameraWorker implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            do {
                boolean hasFrame = false;
                synchronized (MyCameraView.this) {
                    try {
                        while (!mCameraFrameReady && !mStopThread) {
                            MyCameraView.this.wait();
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (mCameraFrameReady)
                    {
                        mChainIdx = 1 - mChainIdx;
                        mCameraFrameReady = false;
                        hasFrame = true;
                    }
                }

                if (!mStopThread && hasFrame) {
                    if (!mFrameChain[1 - mChainIdx].empty())
                        deliverAndDrawFrame(mCameraFrame[1 - mChainIdx]);
                }
            } while (!mStopThread);
            Log.d(TAG, "Finish processing thread");
        }
    }
}
```

Also change the activity_main.xml to as follows:

```
   <com.example.opencvcamera.MyCameraView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/java_camera_view"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

Comment: How do I start it on my activity?